# Queryset filter for django ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to restrict results by overriding

```
def queryset(self, request):
```

within ItemAdmin.

I want to display only the items for which the request.user has been granted category access through the user profile.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(auth.User, unique=True)
    categoryAccess = models.ManyToManyField(Category ...)

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category ...)
```

I can't quite get the syntax right.... I'm trying things like

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ItemAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter( category__in=request.user.objects__profile__categoryAccess )
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double-underscore syntax in filters is only used on the left-hand side of the expression (it's a hack to get round the fact that it's actually a keyword argument to a function, and those can't be expressions). The right-hand side uses the normal syntax to traverse objects: `.` So you probably want this:

```
return qs.filter(category__in=request.user.profile.categoryAccess.all())
```

Note that to make this work you should convert your `user` ForeignKey into a `OneToOneField` (you shouldn't need to migrate the database, just change the model definition).

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thanks so much... I changed the field to OneToOne but I'm getting 'Profile matching query does not exist'.

Comment: Oh whoops! That is my bad actually. The code broke because the user did not have an profile when created. Is it alright to just catch that exception and return an empty list? Thanks for the fix :)

Comment: Just to confirm... the backwards relation user.profile will work, right? I saw that in the documentation backwards relations are possible with the __ syntax. However, when I create a profile and then try to filter: I get a non-traditional Django error. It says "Database error: Something's wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user." Has anyone seen this before?